# Compute the number of shortest paths that use a link

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, shortest-path

I am currently computing shortest path algorithms between two sets of points (origin set and destination set) and a road network, using the plugin QNEAT3. It works and gives me the distances between each point using the road network.
Still, my goal would be to calculate the number of shortest paths that go through a link, to calculate the traffic flow on the network.

I tried to use AequilibraE plugin but I cannot make it work with my layers for now. Do you have hints on what I could do?

Answer (score 1):

@LauC, first a disclaimer: I am the main developer of AequilibraE.

Without any details it is hard to know what problem you are actually having, but a common one is to try and use layers that are MultiLineString, which AequilibraE does not really like.

AequilibraE also performs full traffic assignment, so you can just use it directly for that, but again it is hard to know what your issue is.  AequilibraE does have a user's mailing list to which you can turn to help and fairly decent documentation at [www.aequilibrae.com](http://www.aequilibrae.com)